# Three.js fbx not loading properly

Tags: java, three.js, fbx

Fbx models exported from 3DsMax as FBX in different version loads with black faces even with extremely high sources of light on them.

The version I am trying to load it from is Binary 7400, but I have also tried older/other versions to no avail. Sadly I can't post a picture of what it looks like since my company does not allow imgur on their internet policy... Imagine an FBX with the sides rendered with a material and the front and back side being black. I have other meshes in the scene that don't have that issue as well. Which makes it all the more confusing.

Alternatively I will try to move to GLTF format since that is the recommended step, though it will be hard to move a large amount of models. I was hoping it would work.

Edit: It seems to have to do with some weird behaviour on the meshphysicalmaterial when interacting with my lighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well appears I messed up and forgot about a little detail. The shadowmapping uses the UVs of the mesh, and those were wrong since it was an extrude and I forgot to update my unwrap.